# Объединение и сортировка в SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть запрос на получение данных с джойном многих таблиц. Необходимо отсортировать товары по приоритету поле `int` Но не у каждого товара есть приоритет, поле приоритет со значение `null`. Сортировать необходимо по возрастанию.

Проблема заключается в том, если написать `ORDER BY PRIORITY` то вначале идут товары со значение `null` в приоритете, а затем все остальные:

[image: как тут]

А если указать `ORDER BY PRIORITY IS NOT NULL`, то выходит так:

[image: выходит так]

Возможно отсортировать там где не `null` а потом с `null`?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN PRIORITY IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, PRIORITY`, нет?

Comment: Да, спасибо. Только начинаю свой путь в SQL

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN PRIORITY IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, PRIORITY`